# PiCamera save stream data into image files

Tags: python, io, stream, raspberry-pi

The following example code saves images into a stream.  I would like to know how to save the images in this stream into image files (.jpg etc) on my Pi SD card preferably after all images have been captured to maintain the high FPS.

```
import io
import time
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    # Set the camera's resolution to VGA @40fps and give it a couple
    # of seconds to measure exposure etc.
    camera.resolution = (640, 480)
    camera.framerate = 80
    time.sleep(2)
    # Set up 40 in-memory streams
    outputs = [io.BytesIO() for i in range(40)]
    start = time.time()
    camera.capture_sequence(outputs, 'jpeg', use_video_port=True)
    finish = time.time()
    # How fast were we?
    print('Captured 40 images at %.2ffps' % (40 / (finish - start)))
```

picamera docs:
http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.10/api_camera.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the PIL.  There is also an example in the picam docs.

```
import io
import time
import picamera

from PIL import Image

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    # Set the camera's resolution to VGA @40fps and give it a couple
    # of seconds to measure exposure etc.
    camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
    camera.framerate = 15
    camera.rotation = 180
    time.sleep(2)
    # Set up 40 in-memory streams
    outputs = [io.BytesIO() for i in range(40)]
    start = time.time()
    camera.capture_sequence(outputs, 'jpeg', use_video_port=True)

    finish = time.time()
    # How fast were we?
    print('Captured 40 images at %.2ffps' % (40 / (finish - start)))

    count = 0
    for frameData in outputs:
        rawIO = frameData
        rawIO.seek(0)
        byteImg = Image.open(rawIO)

        count += 1
        filename = "image" + str(count) + ".jpg"
        byteImg.save(filename, 'JPEG')
```